# What are the differences between Qiskit's AerSimulator, QasmSimulator and StatevectorSimulator?

Tags: qiskit, programming, qasm

In Qiskit, we can see the names of available simulators with the command `Aer.backends()`. These include:

```
AerSimulator('aer_simulator')
AerSimulator('aer_simulator_statevector')
AerSimulator('aer_simulator_density_matrix') 
QasmSimulator('qasm_simulator')
StatevectorSimulator('statevector_simulator')
```

What are differences between `AerSimulator('aer_simulator')`, `AerSimulator('aer_simulator_density_matrix')` and `QasmSimulator('qasm_simulator')`? All three seem to perform similar QASM simulation.

Similarly, what are differences between `AerSimulator('aer_simulator_statevector')` and `StatevectorSimulator('statevector_simulator')`?

Comment: Hi user3886914 I think the answer from @Egretta.Thula hits the nail in the head. If you agree that answered your question, please accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Deprecation Note:

- The `StatevectorSimulator` has been superseded by the `AerSimulator` and will be deprecated in the future.
  It has same functionality as `AerSimulator(method="statevector")`.
- The same is true for `QasmSimulator`. It has been superseded by `AerSimulator` and will be deprecated in the future.

#### Difference:

According to the documentation [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/simulators/1_aer_provider.html), the difference between simulation methods like `statevector` and `density_matrix` is:

> The `AerSimulator` supports a variety of simulation methods, each of which supports a different set of instructions. The method can be set manually using `simulator.set_option(method=value)` option, or a simulator backend with a preconfigured method can be obtained directly from the `Aer` provider using `Aer.get_backend`.

> When simulating ideal circuits, changing the method between the exact simulation methods `stabilizer`, `statevector`, `density_matrix` and `matrix_product_state` should not change the simulation result (other than usual variations from sampling probabilities for measurement outcomes)

More information is [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.AerSimulator.html):

> `"statevector"`: A dense statevector simulation that can sample measurement outcomes from ideal circuits with all measurements at end of the circuit. For noisy simulations each shot samples a randomly sampled noisy circuit from the noise model.

> `"density_matrix"`: A dense density matrix simulation that may sample measurement outcomes from noisy circuits with all measurements at end of the circuit.